# TVCardView's focusSizeIncrease not working?

Tags: tvos

I'm trying to manipulate the `focusSizeIncrease` property of a `TVCardView` like this:

```
cardView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
cardView.focusSizeIncrease = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: -10, leading: -10, bottom: -10, trailing: -10)
```

The value of `focusSizeIncrease` is changed when I read it afterwards, but the new value is ignored.

When I read the property in `shouldUpdateFocus(in: UIFocusUpdateContext)` or `didUpdateFocus(in: UIFocusUpdateContext, with: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator)` it has been changed back to the default `NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: -23.0, leading: -23.0, bottom: -23.0, trailing: -23.0)`.

Has anybody got this working?

Apple's Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tvuikit/tvlockupview/2967067-focussizeincrease

Comment: i'm facing same problem, do you found a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

This has fixed by Apple in tvOS 13.